# Django likes button app error - "commit_id" different, but why the value of my cookies ​​are the same?

Tags: python, django, cookies, request

this is my django likes button app config. now,"commit_id" is different, but why the value of the cookies ​​are the same? I want the user to click the button only once in one day, but the following configuration is not successful. I'm a newb. thank you.

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    articles = models.ForeignKey(Articles, related_name='articles_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comment_user_id')
    message = models.TextField(verbose_name = _(u'Comment'))
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta(object):
        db_table = 'articles_comments'
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Comments')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self):
        super(Comments, self).save()
```

views.py:

```
def add_like_to_article_commit(request, commit_id):

    hash_id = hashlib.sha1('commit_id').hexdigest()

    try:
        if 'hash_id' in request.COOKIES:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))

        else:
            commit = Comments.objects.get(id=commit_id)
            commit.likes += 1
            commit.save()
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
            response.set_cookie(commit_id, value=hash_id, max_age=86400)

            return response

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

url.py:

```
url(r'^addLiketoCommit/(?P<commit_id>\d+)/$', 'articles.views.add_like_to_article_commit', name='addLiketoCommit'),
```

issues:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

```
def add_like_to_article_commit(request, commit_id):
    created_date = Comments.objects.get(id=commit_id).created
    hash_id = hashlib.sha1(str(created_date)).hexdigest()

    try:
        if hash_id in str(request.COOKIES.get(commit_id)):     # <------str()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))

        else:
            commit = Comments.objects.get(id=commit_id)
            commit.likes += 1
            commit.save()
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
            response.set_signed_cookie(commit_id, value=hash_id, max_age=86400)

            return response

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

[image]